# Include Javascript in Custom Page Layout (Sandbox Solution)

Tags: javascript, provisioning, token

I provision custom page layout through elements.xml

I want to add a javascript file to that page to be used by some webparts put on that page through elements.xml as well.

In my custom page layout i add

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script src="/SiteAssets/SomeScript.js"></script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

which works fine. But i want this code to be site url independent, meaning this needs to work on any site collection either with managed path or not. How can i inject ~site token into script tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sandbox, you can resolve the tokens using Literals:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

<asp:literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="&lt;script src='" />
<asp:literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/SomeScript.js %>" />
<asp:literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text="' type='text/javascript' &gt;&lt;/script&gt;" />

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong it does not work in sharepoint foundation.

Comment: I doubt the tokens will work on foundation since they are part of the publishing dll which is not present in foundation.

Comment: This does gets job done. But i tried to combine 3 literal into one one, but didn't succeed. It's a bummer, if i have 3 scripts, i need to add 9 lines. Thank you.

Comment: That is sandbox for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<script src="<%= SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativUrl.TrimEnd('/') %>/SiteAssets/SomeScript.js"></script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not allowed in this file


`<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script runat="server" src="<%= SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativUrl.TrimEnd('/') %>/SiteAssets/SomeScript.js"></script>
    </asp:Content>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScriptManagerProxy`, considering your MasterPage already has a ScriptManager (what is true even for OOB Master Page).

With it you can use 'SPUrl` and its tokens.

In you page layout just add:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/my_js_file_path.js %>" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

**But do not add this snipper in the `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead`, you will get exceptions there. Add it to the `PlaceHolderMain`.** Do not worry your scripts files will still be inserted at your page's head.